# Difference between osv.osv class and models.Model class odoo 8

Tags: python-2.7, class, odoo-8

Please let me know difference between osv.osv class and models.Model  class in odoo 8
Example:

```
class account_invoice_line(models.Model):


class account_invoice_line(osv.osv):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **models.Model** is used for the new API introduced at Odoo 8.
  Uses CamelCase as syntax `class AccountInvoiceLine(models.Model):`
- **osv.osv** is used for backwards compatibility with the old OpenERP 7 code. Uses underscore syntax `class account_invoice_line(osv.osv):`

If you're writing a module for Odoo 8 or higher I'd suggest using the new Odoo 8 models.Model instead of osv.osv.

Answer (score 1):

osv.osv is the old API (prior to odoo 8) but models.Model is the new API

Answer (score -1):

They have used C++ for the OSV Kernel Development with various data structures and algorithms. Linux Kernel is developed using C with the use of various data structures as well.

OSV is mainly designed to run on the cloud as it reduces the memory and cpu overhead when compared with other operating systems

Comment: This answer seems to have nothing to do with the question. The OSV being asked about is "Object Services" - see https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/what-does-osv-mean-in-openerp-modules-17978 - not the OSv operating system....